# Couchbase (ex. membase) solution to dump all keys in a bucket

Tags: php, key, dump, membase, couchbase

I was googling around and found various python + tap solutions that should enable me to dump all keys from a bucket but none of them worked for me. I have a bucket at port 11230 and I need to get a dump of all keys in order to fill them into sphinx search engine.

If I execute:

```
# python /opt/couchbase/lib/python/tap_example.py 127.0.0.1:11230
```

I get the following output:

```
info: New bin connection from None
error: uncaptured python exception, closing channel <tap.TapConnection connected at 0x7f5d287184d0> (<type 'exceptions.AssertionError'>: [/usr/lib/python2.6/asyncore.py|read|78] [/usr/lib/python2.6/asyncore.py|handle_read_event|428] [/opt/couchbase/lib/python/mc_bin_server.py|handle_read|325])
```

this error is the same even if I try some other host or port. I also tried many other python scripts that I found on forums and groups but all of them produced the same error.

My primary development environment includes PHP & Perl on Debian linux box but I will take any solution that would just dump all the keys into plain text file.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Late reply, but you could use a couchbase view for this.

```
function (doc, meta) {
  if(meta.type == 'json') {
   emit(doc.key, null);    
  }
}
```

This would emit every key in the bucket that is json.